# How do I grab (webscrape) all products from a website with multiple categories/subcategories?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I was given the task to webscrape all items from a page called Officeworks using Selenium and a few other packages on Python.

The thing is I don't really have a strong basis with Python and I don't know how to webscrape items from multiple categories. I only know how to grab the items from one single category (which ever one I specify) and I would like to grab all the items from the whole entire store.

My code is shown below.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import selenium.webdriver.support.ui as ui
import selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions as EC
import os
import time
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
options.add_argument('--ignore-ssl-errors')

os.chdir("C:/Users/cameron.deng/Desktop/Scripts/python scraping")
cwd = os.getcwd()
main_dir = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(cwd, os.pardir))
print('Main Directory:', main_dir)

chromedriver = os.path.abspath(main_dir) + "/chromedriver"
os.environ["webdriver.chrome.driver"] = chromedriver

browser = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path=chromedriver)
browser.get("https://www.officeworks.com.au/shop/officeworks/c/education/book/literacy-books")



lenOfPage = browser.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);var lenOfPage=document.body.scrollHeight;return lenOfPage;")
match = False
while (match == False):
    lastCount = lenOfPage
    time.sleep(10)
    lenOfPage = browser.execute_script(
        "window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);var lenOfPage=document.body.scrollHeight;return lenOfPage;")
    if lastCount == lenOfPage:
        match = True

page = browser.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')



while True:
    time.sleep(10)
    res = pd.DataFrame()
    for sec in soup.findAll('div', attrs={'id': 'productList'}):
        for div in sec.findAll('div', attrs={'class': 'ow-product-tile product'}):
            pId = div["id"]
            pCatId = div["data-catentryid"]
            pTitle = div.findAll("img")[0]["alt"]
            temp = pd.DataFrame({'itemId': [pId], 'itemCatId': [pCatId], 'itemTitle': [pTitle]})
            res = res.append(temp)
        browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#paginationViewFullWidth > nav > ul > li.ow-pagination__next > a').click()
```

The results show the item informations which is shown in the data frame.

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "how to webscrape items from multiple categories.". What are these categories?

Comment: _...grab (webscrape) all products..._ which products?

Comment: Categories such as Office Supplies, Stationary, Computers, Services and so on.

Comment: You could use the sitemap file to help you navigate all the site pages: [Office Works Site Map](https://www.officeworks.com.au/sitemap.xml). There seems to be a link there to the site categories: [Office Works Categories](https://www.officeworks.com.au/sitemap-categories.xml). Hopefully the structure on each page is similar so you can re-use your selenium code.

Comment: Is it possible to reference this list of addresses (categories) to this code? 

secondcat = []
for link in page_soup.findAll("a",attrs={"class":"ow-accordion-menu__item ow-accordion-menu__item"}):
    secondcat.append(urljoin(mainurl,link.get("href")))